# Creating a list with input from askopenfile() from tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, brute-force

I am having a problem creating a list with askopenfile() with a password file. I have it working with usernames but since rockyou.txt and password files have special characters I had to convert it to UTF-8 and the same method I am using for usernames is producing a list character by character rather then word by word.

**user name:**

```
def open_file():
    file = askopenfile(mode ='r', filetypes =[('Text Files', '*.txt')])
    content = []
    userlist = []
    if file is not None:
        content = file.readlines()
        for line in content:
            userlist.append(line.strip('\n'))
        print(userlist)
```

**username output:**

```
['3d', 'a', 'a1', 'aa', 'aaberg', 'aachen', 'aalborg', 'aalesund', 'aalii', 'aalst', 'aalto', 'aam', 'aara', 'aarau']
```

(just a portion because its super long but the ideas there)

**password:**

```
def open_file2():
    file2 = askopenfile(mode ='rb', filetypes =[('Text Files', '*.txt')])
    content2 = []
    passlist = []
    if file2 is not None:
        content2 = file2.read().decode('utf-8')
        for line in passes:
            passlist.append(line.strip('\n'))
        print(passlist)
```

**password output:**

```
['!', '!', '!', '4', '5', '4', '5', '\r', '\n', '!', '"', '¹', '1', '2', '3', '\r', '\n', '!', '"', '¹', ';', '1', '2', '3', '4', '\r', '\n']
```

(also just a portion)

But yeah, the issue is the password list is being created character by character instead of word to word. Is there a way to make it word to word in the method I am currently using? Also is there a better way to open the file that is similar to the first way?

If anyone is alarmed to answer, this is for my final project(cyber security). I am now just trying to convert it to a GUI to spice things up a little.

Comment: I think your first assumption about having to convert to utf8 is wrong ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your main issue is

`for line in passes:`

It should be `for line in content2.splitlines():` ... I think ... I also am skeptical about the need to convert to utf8 ...but meh

dont decode your string to utf8 ... just use the bytes

```
def open_file2():
    file2 = askopenfile(mode ='rb', filetypes =[('Text Files', '*.txt')])
    content2 = []
    passlist = []
    if file2 is not None:
        content2 = file2.read()
        for line in content2.splitlines():
            passlist.append(line.strip(b'\n')) # make sure to use bytes here
        print(passlist)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried your recommendation but it seemed to give the same thing. Also, is there a different way I should go about it? When I try reading the file this way:
 def open_file2():
    file2 = askopenfile(mode ='r', filetypes =[('Text Files', '*.txt')])
    content2 = []
    passlist = []
    if file2 is not None:
        content2 = file2.readlines()
        #passlist = list(content2)
        for line in content2:
            passlist.append(line.strip('\n'))
        print(passlist)

Comment: i get:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 2023: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: `passes` is not defined ... `content2` appears to be the text content of the file ... ignore the utf8 comment as that is unlikely your issue .... you need to split the content2 using `content2.splitlines()` to return individual lines instead of every character (not sure of the format of these files ... you might need to do `content2.split("something")` other than lines

Comment: based on your error it actually seems like it has alot to do with your decode call ...